# Passing StyleSheet to a react component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

I have an styles file in my project, where I have defined some stylesheets. Now in my App.tsx, I import those stylesheets and I want to pass them to a component that I create as a prop.

styles.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    t1: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'flex-end'
    },
    t2: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'flex-start'
    },
});
export style;
```

component.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const Component = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={props.style1}>
            <View style={props.style2}>
                <Text>
                    just a text
                </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};
export default Component;
```

app.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import Component from './component';
import style from './styles';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Component style1={style.t1} style2={style.t2} />
    );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but **not recommended** to pass StyleSheet like this. BTW, You're on the right track.

Since you are using Typescript, it's important to declare the type.

**styles.tsx**

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    t1: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'flex-end'
    },
    t2: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'flex-start'
    },
});

export default styles; // Use 'export default' to export the styles object
```

**component.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';

interface ComponentProps  {
    style1: ViewStyle; // Specify the type for style1
    style2: ViewStyle; // Specify the type for style2
}

const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={props.style1}>
            <View style={props.style2}>
                <Text>
                    just a text
                </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

export default Component;
```

**app.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Component from './component';
import styles from './styles'; 

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Component style1={styles.t1} style2={styles.t2} />
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: How is the recommended way then? I have one component which I use it many times with different styles.

Comment: Besides, I have tried this code and, unfortunately the only output that I get is a blank screen.

Comment: Check it out: https://snack.expo.dev/@arvind.1/healthy-blue-kiwi